# How to only shown one table after clicking search button?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a 2 tables like this when I search the member name. 
link :

[image]

I wanted the search result to be shown only after search.

my code:

```
            <div id = "subtitle">
            View Members
            </div>
            <div id = "searchbox">
            <form method="post">
<center><input type="text"  maxlength="100"  required placeholder="Enter Full Name" name ="search" autocomplete="off" value="">
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="SEARCH NOW!"></p></center>

            </form>
            </div>

            <?php

     if(isset($_POST["btn"]))

     {
         $search = $_POST["search"]; 
         $sql = "select * from member where Member_Name like '$search%' "; 
         $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
         $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
         if($rowcount==0)
             echo "Sorry ,no records found!"; 
         else
         {
            ?>
        <center><table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                      <th>Member ID</th>
                      <th>Member Name</th>
                      <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
    <?php
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  //display
            {
    ?>          <tr>
                    <td></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row["Member_ID"]?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row["Member_Name"]?></td>
                      <td><a href=Admin_MemberDetails.php?id=".$row["Member_ID"]."><img src=../Images/ViewFile.png height=37px title=View></a>
                      <a href=Admin_EditMember.php?id=".$row["Member_ID"]."><img src=../Images/edit.png height=37px title=Edit></a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </center>
    <?php
            }           
         }
     }


    ?>

            <center><table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>#</th>
                      <th>Member ID</th>
                      <th>Member Name</th>
                      <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>

      <?php

      $sql = "select * from legoclub_guesthouse.member";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $rowcount= mysqli_num_rows($result);

      while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
      {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td></td>";
        echo "<td>$row[Member_ID]</td>";
        echo "<td>$row[Member_Name]</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=Admin_MemberDetails.php?id=".$row["Member_ID"]."><img src=../Images/ViewFile.png height=37px title=View></a>
                  <a href=Admin_EditMember.php?id=".$row["Member_ID"]."><img src=../Images/edit.png height=37px title=Edit></a>
              </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
      }


      ?>

      </table><center>

            </div>
```

Please include the php file for me too!

Comment: why dont you combine all the result for one table ? Use `Mysql UNION` if no relation in both tables, or you can merge the data in one `array` for loop.

Comment: I am sorry that I have lack out something. I want to only show the search result if I search. But I want the full member list to be shown if I did not search. Which mean if I search, the search result will be covering the full member list.

Answer (score 0):

To do it in easiest way just try to use this code:

```
<div id = "subtitle">
            View Members
            </div>
            <div id = "searchbox">
            <form method="post">
<center><input type="text"  maxlength="100"  required placeholder="Enter Full Name" name ="search" autocomplete="off" value="">
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="SEARCH NOW!"></p></center>

            </form>
            </div>

            <?php

     if(isset($_POST["btn"]))

     {
         $search = $_POST["search"]; 
         $sql = "select * from member where Member_Name like '$search%' "; 
         $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
         $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
         if($rowcount==0)
             echo "Sorry ,no records found!"; 
         else
         {
            ?>
        <center><table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                      <th>Member ID</th>
                      <th>Member Name</th>
                      <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
    <?php
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  //display
            {
    ?>          <tr>
                    <td></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row["Member_ID"]?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row["Member_Name"]?></td>
                      <td><a href=Admin_MemberDetails.php?id=".$row["Member_ID"]."><img src=../Images/ViewFile.png height=37px title=View></a>
                      <a href=Admin_EditMember.php?id=".$row["Member_ID"]."><img src=../Images/edit.png height=37px title=Edit></a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
    <?php
            }
            $sql = "select * from legoclub_guesthouse.member";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            $rowcount= mysqli_num_rows($result);
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td></td>";
              echo "<td>$row[Member_ID]</td>";
              echo "<td>$row[Member_Name]</td>";
              echo "<td><a href=Admin_MemberDetails.php?id=".$row["Member_ID"]."><img src=../Images/ViewFile.png height=37px title=View></a>
                        <a href=Admin_EditMember.php?id=".$row["Member_ID"]."><img src=../Images/edit.png height=37px title=Edit></a>
                    </td>";
              echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>
                </table>
                </center>
<?php
         }
     }


    ?>

            </div>
```

But I would recommend you to use [SQL UNION Operator.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

It will make your life easy for these type of problems

Comment: I am sorry that I have lack out something. I want to only show the search result if I search. But I want the full member list to be shown if I did not search. Which mean if I search, the search result will be covering the full member list.

Comment: If user clicks on search button you will have to use isset() and else for yourother condition that if user does not click on search buton

Comment: Can you do one simple for me?